# find all unique permissions web, list and item powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, sharepoint-addin, unique

How to Find Unique Permissions in SharePoint for All Items, Lists and web? and i need in csv user whom has access to this web list and item ? any help?

Comment: What SharePoint version? There is a couple of scripts out on the web. https://spuniquepermissions.codeplex.com/

Comment: sharepoint 2013

Comment: What have you done till now? Any code written?

Comment: i totally doesnt know how do this, but i find something, and i have idea to write code like this for web and list, what do you think about this ? http://soreddymanjunath.blogspot.com/2014/06/find-list-items-having-unique.html